# Prepositional phrases. Help to sort into the right order

Tags: prepositions, modifiers

I fill like something is wrong in the phrase bellow. Could someone explain how the phrase in bold should be formed?

We talked just as easily as we had in the past, when we would sit ***in the field behind Joan’s house atop the rabbit hutch*** and discuss our friends and our hopes for the future.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I would say to avoid multiple prepositional phrases in a row. If you must order these phrases, your ordering seems okay to me.

But I think this ordering is more senseful: **'atop the rabbit hutch in the field behind Joan's house'.**